# How to return an object from an array with the same type of that item in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm creating a sample method inspired by ruby's sample method that returns a random object from the array within bounds.

My method works fine, and I can call it like this:

```
questions.Sample<Question>();
```

And the function's source currently looks like this:

```
public static class ArrayUtils
{
    public static T Sample<T>(this IList list)
    {
        var type = list[0].GetType();
        return (T) list[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, list.Count)];
    }
}
```

So the problem is, rather than including the type that I want to return, I'd like it to just return the type of the objects in the array.

For example, if we have an array of type Question[], it should return an object of type Question.

Basically, in code, I want to change this:

```
questions.Sample<Question>();
```

To this:

```
questions.Sample();
```

---

Thanks for any help,

Bilal

Comment: What would you expect the compile-time type of that method call to be?

Comment: If you do not care about the return type then do away with the generic argument all together. Otherwise you could use a generic `List<T>` and you would not have to specify it.

Comment: public static class ArrayUtils
{
    public static IList[] Sample(this IList list)
    {
        var type = list[0].GetType();
        return (IList[])list[1];
    }
}

Comment: How (without using generics) would you put a return type on your method (other than `object`) if you don't know what that's going to be at design time?

Comment: I was afraid that it would be a static language problem. Just wanted to check if anyone had some intuition I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really only have 3 options.

Option 1 - you can do this if you really do not care about the type that is being returned. The result will always be returned as `object`.

```
public static object Sample(this IList list)
{
    return list[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, list.Count)];
}
```

*If you are using value types in your list boxing will occur when the result is returned as an object. Thanks for pointing that out @rory.ap*

Option 2 - If you are using a generic `IList<T>` then you can do this in which case the generic specicier is copied from the parameter that is being used on.

```
public static T Sample<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    return list[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, list.Count)];
}
```

Option 3 - this is what you have already and you must specify the generic type.

```
public static T Sample<T>(this IList list)
{
    return (T)list[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, list.Count)];
}
```

Comment: Note that boxing will occur in option 1.